# If I pass light through a conducting ring will I get an emf induced in the ring? Also if I do get an emf would that not violate energy conservation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, visible-light, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Here is what I think should happen. Light being an electromagnetic wave should have an oscillating magnetic component which should constantly change the flux linked with the conductor. Hence an emf should be induced in the ring.

Comment: But light is also a particle as photon. how can you show the theory for this contradiction? Also light has a changing magnetic field but also a changing electric field which may cancel the emf generated due to Lenz Law?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ring can absorb some of the electromagnetic wave's energy.  What you're thinking is the basis of a loop antenna:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna